# FastAPI 422 Error: Unprocessable Entity when use GET method

Tags: python, fastapi

I got 422 Error when try to make 'search functionality'. this is my code:

ROUTERS

```
@router.get('/search')
def search(query: Optional[str], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return librarian.search_book(query, db)
```

LIBRARIAN

```
def search_book(query: Optional[str], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    res = db.query(models.Book).filter(models.Book.title.contains(query)).all()
    return res
```

MODELS

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    isbn = Column(String)
    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    author = Column(String)
    status_peminjaman = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    tanggal_peminjaman = Column(Date, default=null, nullable=True)
```

[Eror Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8awq0.png)

[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOYh8.png)

Comment: def search_book(query: Optional[str], db: Session) no need to duplicate Depends

Comment: Also please share exact request

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The error is referring to an `id` in the request that seems to be expected to be an integer but is "not a valid integer". The posted codes don't seem to show that same route from the error with the `id`, and you didn't also show the exact request.

Comment: Can you refresh the /docs page, try again, and make the screenshot with the whole request not just the 422 error ?

Comment: im sorry, i've added the screenshot of the request

Comment: It seems like you've mounted your router beneath a path with `{id}` in it, without it being submitted (or that you have a `librarian/search/{id}` route or something similar. Since the error message says that it expects an `{id}` parameter in the route, I'd start by finding out which endpoint is _actually_ being called first.

Answer (score 1):

The error response indicates that the `id` path parameter type is [mismatched](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#data-validation) with the function's parameter type annotation.

Just like @MatsLindh said, it could be [the order of path operations](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters) (i.e. there's a function with path `/librarian/search/{id}` defined before the `search` function you posted).

Taking a modified example from the docs, this would give a similar error when you try to access the `/users/me` path (since the path will be matched with the first path operation):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/users/{user_id}")
async def read_user(user_id: int):
    return {"user_id": user_id}


@app.get("/users/me")
async def read_user_me():
    return {"user_id": "the current user"}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I can see that the big challenge is you need pydantic models to provide a response to HTTP from FastAPI*, so let's resolve it with an example.

1.- First, let's create the model Book which represents the books table in the database.

```
# models.py 

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

from .database import Base


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    isbn = Column(String(50))
    title = Column(String(150))
    description = Column(String(250))
    author = Column(String(150))
```

2.- Now create Pydantic models (schemas) that will be used when reading data, and when returning it from the API.

In this case we are going to create 3 classes in schemas.py file, but why?

1. **BookBase(BaseModel)** -> In this class I will include all the tributes that are common when I create a book or when I return the information from it as a response to the user.
2. **Bookcreate(BookBase)** -> This class ins going to help me to create a book in my database, but why this class is empty?, well this is due to pydantic allows us to use inheritance in its classes, so this class inheriting from BookBase already contains the same attributes as the parent class and I save rewriting them, this is very powerful .
3. **BookOut(BaseModel)** -> this is the class that we're going to use to return a response model with the books' field that we want our user reads from our API.

If you need more information about it, check this [FastAPI schemas Pydantic](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/?h=sql#create-pydantic-models-schemas-for-reading-returning)

```
# schemas.py

from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class BookBase(BaseModel):
    isbn: Optional[str] = Field(None, max_length=50, example="973-2-1234-5680-3")
    title: Optional[str] = Field(None, max_length=150, example="Surfear la vida")
    description: Optional[str] = Field(None, max_length=250, example="Jaimal Yogis deja la secundaria urbana para escapar a Hawái.")
    author: Optional[str] = Field(None, max_length=150, example="Jaimal Yogis")
    

class BookCreate(BookBase):
    pass 


class BookOut(BookBase):
   id: int = Field(..., gt=0, example=1)
   
   class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

3.- Okay, let's move on to create the functionality of the filter with SQLAlchemy in our crud.py file.

See more information in this link: [crud utils FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/?h=sql#crud-utils)

```
# crud.py

from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models

def get_books(db: Session, title: Optional[str] = None, description: Optional[str] = None, author: Optional[str] = None):
    """Get all books using SQLAlchemy query with the operator and_

    Args:
        db (Session): database session/connection
        title (Optional[str], optional): book title sent as query parameter.  Defaults to None.
        description (Optional[str], optional): book description sent as query parameter. Defaults to None.
        author (Optional[str], optional): book author sent as query parameter. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        The list of all books or an empty array if no book is registered
    """
        
    query_books = db.query(models.Book)
    
    if title:
        query_books = query_books.filter(
            and_(models.Book.title.ilike(f"%{title}%"))
        )
    if description:
        query_books = query_books.filter(
            and_(models.Book.description.ilike(f"%{description}%"))
        )
    if author:
        query_books = query_books.filter(
            and_(models.Book.author.ilike(f"%{author}%"))
        )
    
    return query_books.order_by(models.Book.id.desc()).all()
```

4.- And now in the file app/main.py let's integrate and use all the other parts we created before, and create a path operation that allows us to filter information with the books.

I invite you to check this documentation [Main FastAPI app](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/?h=sql#main-fastapi-app)

Important things to check in the path operation:
response_model=List[schemas.BookOut]: We use a response model based on our schemas and help us to determine the type of result that we are going to show in the API response.

Why we use List? : This is a special case due to we are going to return a collection of books, so it is going to be conformable to keep it in a list to return the response .

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, status, Depends

from typing import List, Optional
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# import crud.py file
from . import crud, schemas, models

# In a very simplistic way create the database tables:
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()


# Now use the SessionLocal class we created in the sql_app/database.py file to create a dependency.
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.get(path="/")
def index():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get(path="/books", response_model=List[schemas.BookOut] , status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, tags=['Books'])
def get_books(
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    title: Optional[str] = Query(None, min_length=1, max_length=150),
    description: Optional[str] = Query(None, min_length=1, max_length=250),
    author: Optional[str] = Query(None, min_length=1, max_length=150),
):
    books = crud.get_books(db=db, title=title, description=description, author=author)
    return books
```

Now when you implement this path operation */books* with the Query parameters and the correct response model that you need, you'll be able to filter the information and avoid having this error of *unprocessable entity*.

Results:
[Get all books from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDcHX.png)
[Apply filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXWt.png)

If you need more information, this is the [repository of the project](https://github.com/javieramayapat/book-search) in which I create an example of this challenge ‍♂️.

Regards!